# Dropdownlist shows duplicate values while editing a row in the gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

Well the dropdownlist has an existing items. I just want the selected gridview record to be displayed in the dropdownlist. The dropdownlist has several DataTextField in string and consist of DataValueField in numeric.
The gridview passes a string text to the box which has an equal or same item inside the dropdownlist. Whenever i passed a record from a gridview to be viewed in the dropdownlist it just duplicates the same item.
Q: How can i simply pass a text inside the dropdown and just simply display it without adding on the list.

sample item on the dropdown:
--Select--
Account
Savings

after selecting on the gridview and display inside the dropdown:
Account
Account
Savings

(you see the '--Select--' was erase and replace with the selected record)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you have a table where one column is a lookup from a selection list.

When you're editing the list, you want to select the item in the drop down that corresponds to the displayed item in the normal view mode.

If that's the case, you want to get the select `ID` or the selected `Text` for the dropdown.

If you're using the numeric ID then you want:

```
Dropdownlist.Items.FindByValue(value).Selected = true;
```

If you're using the text then you want:

```
DropDownList.SelectedValue = DropDownList.Items.FindByText("Text").Value
```

Answer (score 0):

From your text it seems you are adding items to a dropdownlist while you just want to change selection based on the Text property.
To achieve that you can just do:

```
DropDownListId.Text = "text value";
```

That should work, but I didn't test it.

Comment: --Select--                                                         Account